# Mongoose Add If To Middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I am not sure if this is a Mongoose or Nodejs Express error?

I would just like to know if there is a way to add middleware in the form of an if. This is my call:

```
app.post(pPath, auth, (req, res) => {
    ...
})
```

And I would just like to do something like this:

```
app.post(pPath, varBoolean ? auth : null, (req, res) => {
    ...
})
```

The above example does not work though. Any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express methods don't support non-function handlers. This is generally a good thing because this allows to detect problems with imports on application start.

This can be achieved with a spread:

```
app.post(...[pPath, varBoolean && auth, (req, res) => {
    ...
}].filter(Boolean))
```

Comment: This works perfectly man. Quite crazy haha, I don't really understand what it does yet. Well done!...and thanks for the explanation on the handlers!

Comment: You're welcome It filters out falsy value (`varBoolean`, in case it's falsy) from a list of arguments. It's similar to `if (varBoolean) app.post(pPath, auth, (req, res) =>...) else app.post(pPath, (req, res) =>...)`, which is what you wanted, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using 'app.use', if you want to have a middleware in place.

```
app.use('/path', (req, res, next) => {
const { test } = req.body;
const { auth } = req.headers;
if(!test) {
return res.status(400).json({message: 'Missing field test'});
}
const validToken = await tokenValidation(auth);
if(!validToken){
return res.status(403).json({message: 'Unauthorized'});
}
next();
});
```